# getting "ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "max_parallel_workers_per_gather" while doing parallel processing in Postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

**My Code**

```
  SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2;
```

**Error**

```
ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "max_parallel_workers_per_gather"
```

**Note**- While using Postgres SQL when i want to enable parallel processing, I am getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: That was introduced in Postgres 9.6 and won't work (or even have any effect) on the outdated (and unsupported) version 9.1. You need to upgrade to Postgres 9.6 or 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using postgresql 9.6 and I got no error.

Here's how I did it:

open `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf` with root permission
uncomment `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` and set the value accordingly.
save it and then just restart the postgresql by

sudo service postgresql restart

Inside of postgresql.conf:-

```
max_worker_processes = 8               # (change requires restart)
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4     # taken from max_worker_processes
```